# A web page with a random street view

Tags: random, google-street-view

for an artistic/architectural exhibition we need to create a simple web page with
a street view container with random destination. (everytime the page is loaded)

how I can integrate the html + scritp that i find in this page
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/streetview-embed

to work fine?

Comment: Hi, it looks like you found the documentation page already, it should be able to help you with that. If you run into problems and need help with something specific, please post your code and explain your problem.

Answer (score 0):

First of all I am referring to [this example of google developers](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/streetview-service).

I would utilize StreetViewService to find panorama closest to random point in the earth, when it does not find one I would try generating another point.

For the sake of example:

```
function generateRandomPoint()
{
    sv.getPanoramaByLocation
        (new google.maps.LatLng(
            Math.random()*180 - 90,
            Math.random()*360 - 180), 
            500,
            processSVData);
}
```

Then modify the processSVData to:

```
function processSVData(data, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.StreetViewStatus.OK) {
    ....
  } else generateRandomPoint();
}
```

Ofcourse you will propably need to strip the example I reffered to from the map but that should be easy.